# Change the working directory of R plots through C#

Tags: c#, r, process, cmd

I have run the `RScript` through command by invoking process , In this case my script file containing the following lines

```
data<-read.csv("insurance.csv")
hist(data$children)
```

After executing this lines `Rplots.pdf` file generated in the current working directory of R

Is it possible to change the working directory of R plots through C# ?

Comment: I probably missing something, but why can't you just add `setwd` to your R script?

Comment: Create a string with the target directory path, and pass it as an argument to your script so it knows where to save the files.

Comment: Or, it'll be probably enough to just navigate to the desired dir before you call Rscript.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the working directory of R plots by using the following R Script before plot the Graph

pdf(file = "D:\RScripts\Rplots.pdf")